# Remote OpenSCManager fails with access denied

Tags: windows, service, windows-security, sc.exe

I am attempting to control a service on a remote machine using the following code:

```
// Error checking omitted for brevity
HANDLE hToken = NULL;
// user = username with no domain specification
// domain = targetmachine when targetting computer outside of domain
LogonUser(user, domain, password,
    LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, &hToken);

ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken);

SC_HANDLE hSc = OpenSCManager(targetmachine,
                    SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
```

This works fine when run from a computer within our local domain and targetting a machine on the same domain, both when using the credentials from the currently logged on user as well as when using other credentials.

However, when I attempt to target a machine that is not on any domain, the `OpenSCManager` call fails with access denied if I specify anything other than `SC_MANAGER_CONNECT` as the desired access. Targetting a domain computer from a computer that is outside the domain works (using user/domain/password combination for a domain user that is a local administrator on the target machine). Targetting a computer outside the domain from a computer outside the domain does not work.

The user/password is for a member of the administrator group on the target computer, so there should not be a problem with the account rights.

I've checked the scmanager security descriptor using `sc -sdshow scmanager` and it is identical for the domain computer and the non-domain computer. Both are running Windows 7 64-bit.

I've also tested to use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553), which has the same symptoms, i.e. works fine between domain computers but not when targetting non-domain computer.

I have also tested to disable RPC over TCP on the target machine and rebooting it, as this is [described as a possible cause for access denied errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd578505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but this does not appear to help. I've also tested to disable the Windows Firewall on the targetmachine, but no change.

**Is there some setting that needs to be enabled in order for remote configuration of services to work?**

Comment: You're likely to get a better response at serverfault.com

Comment: @HansPassant: You're probably right. I was kind of hoping that I would have done something wrong in my code, which is more likely to be spotted by someone here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that this was caused by new security features from Windows Vista and above. By default, Windows will not grant remotely connecting users full administrator rights unless it is being done within a domain. So in order for this to work, [User Account Control Remote Restrictions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016) need to be turned off, but of course this will also lower the security of your computer.

Thanks to Hans Passant for recommending to check for [similar issues posted on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/111007/having-trouble-using-psservice-and-sc-exe-between-windows-server-2008-machines).

Comment: Keyword: `Failed to open SC Manager Error: 5 Message: Access is denied`