# remote sc OpenSCManager query failed 5 access denied

Tags: permissions, cmd, windows-xp, mmc, service-control-manager

I'm writing a script that periodically checks that certain services are running on remote workstations.  I'm having a devil of a time getting an "SC \workst1 query" command working from one test machine to another.  Both machines are running XP pro SP3.  Neither is part of a domain.  Both are in the same workgroup, and the administrator accounts have the same passwords.

I keep getting the "[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5: Access is denied" message, from either workstation to the other.  I have tried using elevated privileges on both. Windows firewall software is turned off.  There are no messages are showing up in the Event security logs.  When (as administrator) I try going to "Computer Management" -> "connect to another computer" and access the remote services I get "Error 5 Access is denied".

I can set up a filesystem share between the two machines successfully, and "net use \workst1\IPC$ /user:Administrator" completes successfully, but the SC query still fails.  I'm using IP addresses and not hostnames in these commands, but that doesn't help.  I don't know what else to try.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Related and possible answer: [SO: Remote OpenSCManager fails with access denied](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8472174/1608670)

Answer (score 30):

Try to run the commans as a Administrator

start-> (type **cmd** in search box), right click on **cmd**, **Run as a administrator** -> execute your command

Answer (score 24):

You must have administrative rights on the remote machine.
Moreover you must access the drive before calling "sc".
This can be achieved in command line using

```
net use \\remotemachine\admin$ <password> /user:<username>
```

admin$ is a hidden shared drive accessible to administrators that "sc" uses to control services.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue today trying to check if a service is enabled remotely.
I could solve the issue modifying the User Account Control for remote restrictions in windows:

To disable UAC remote restrictions, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, type `regedit`, and then press ENTER.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
3. If the `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` registry entry does not exist,
           follow these steps:
     On the `Edit` menu, point to `New`, and then click `DWORD Value`. Type `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy`, and then press ENTER. 
     Right-click `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy`, and then click `Modify`. In the `Value` data box, type `1`, and then click OK.
4. Exit Registry Editor.

More information about this solution in [this site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942817/how-to-change-the-remote-uac-localaccounttokenfilterpolicy-registry-setting-in-a-windows-vista-image).

Comment: I added this Registry key and then was able to query the remote machine if I ran `sc` / `psservice` in an Administrator command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Your user should be remote, from Manage and Local users and groups

Answer (score 0):

The UAC issue is obvious you have to pull down the lever for UAC setting 
Also while installing the services you can use the following command

SC create SERVICENAME DisplayName= "DISPLAYNAME" binPath= "PATH OF EXE" start= disabled type= share